# Hosting app on Heroku and using a DNS provider that does not support root CNAME

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I have my app deployed on Heroku and for my domain I am using a DNS provider that does not offer setting CNAME records at root level as Heroku requires.

I added my domain example.com on Heroku and it provided me with a DNS target of .herokudns.com, however, since I am unable to set root CNAME record on my DNS provider, I have set the above target to point to www.example.com, which makes the HTTP challenge on Heroku to fail.

Instead to make it work, I added www.example.com on Heroku, but this, if I understand it correctly, will not work for users who want to visit example.com without www and will affect existing SEO scores.

What is the recommended course of action here?

Comment: There is no magic which will make plain example.com work if the DNS provider does not allow you to configure this domain. This means if you want to have this you need to switch the DNS provider for your domain.

Comment: I agree with @SteffenUllrich , if you want Heroku to use the root-domain, you need a DNS-provider that supports a `ANAME ` record type. 

Another workaround could be: 
- let heroku use `www.` 
- let your DNS-Provider redirect the root-domain to `www.`
This complicates the SSL-Setup though.